# Question regarding releases after August 1st

Tags: android

so we know that starting August 1st releases need to support 64bits, my question is regarding split builds where you have 32bit and 64bit apks separately, would this still be an option? because building both in a single apk increases the file size dramatically

Comment: Nope. But you can create a procedure to download only 32 or 64 bit libraries.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's recommendation, you can use Android App Bundle to reduce the size. As stated in documentation:

> Mitigating size increases with Android App Bundle
>   Adding 64-bit architecture support to your app can cause your APK size to grow. We strongly recommend taking advantage of the Android App Bundle feature to minimize the size impact of including both 32- and 64-bit native code in the same APK.
>   Switching your app to using Android App Bundles can actually be an improvement to your APK size, reducing it to less than what it is right now.

Take a look at [Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/).

There is no way to have separate builds unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Yes.
I am using a native library and after i made split apks for both 32 and 64, `Google Play Console` stoped giving me warnings about missing `64bit` version. So i guess it should be enough (Google Play will balance which device gets which apk) . [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split)

Comment: you don't get a warning when uploading the 32bit apk? isn't this what the new rule is trying to prevent? or am I missing something

Comment: Split build will give you separate apks(2 in my case), you upload both 32bit and 64bit with different version codes for the same release.